# Function runs immediately without setTimeout() in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, mysql

I want to build a web with HTML, CSS, Javascript, PHP and MySQL. I want my web will have a feature that the customers want to download the file from the web, if they don't want to download faster, no need to go through the shorten link, they will enter the code and web will use PHP and MySQL to check if the code is in the database. If the code valid, they will press the Next button to go to download file.
This is all my code:

HTML + CSS + JS + PHP:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML Document</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
function countWord() {
var x = document.getElementById("code").value;
if ((x.length)!=12) {
document.getElementById("ok").disabled = true;
} else if ((x.length)==12) {
document.getElementById("ok").disabled = false;
}
}
</script>
<style>
* {
padding:0;
margin:0;
box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
background-color:#fff;
}
#code {
width:98%;
margin-left:1%;
}
#ok {
width:50%;
margin-left:25%;
margin-top:10px;
}
#nextbtn {
width:50%;
margin-left:25%;
margin-top:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" name="code_form" id="code_form">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="code" id="code" onkeyup="countWord();">
<input type="submit" name="ok" id="ok" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>
</form>
<button type="button" disabled class="btn btn-primary" id="nextbtn">Next</button>

<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("","","","");
if (isset($_POST["ok"])) {
$code = $_POST["code"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM code WHERE code='$code'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
echo "
<script>
var x = setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById('nextbtn').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('nextbtn').onclick = function() {
window.open('https://www.youtube.com');
};
},0);
</script>
";
} else {
echo "<script>alert('Error');</script>";
}
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

In the code below, I want to be able to run the function immediately without using the setTimeout() function:

```
echo "
<script>
var x = setTimeout(function(){
document.getElementById('nextbtn').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('nextbtn').onclick = function() {
window.open('https://www.youtube.com');
};
},0);
</script>
";
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will be invoked immediately. [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

```js
(function(){
document.getElementById('nextbtn').disabled = false;
document.getElementById('nextbtn').onclick = function() {
window.open('https://www.youtube.com');
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Is removing the `setTimeout` only not enough?

```
<script>
 (function(){
   document.getElementById('nextbtn').disabled = false;
   document.getElementById('nextbtn').onclick = function() {
   window.open('https://www.youtube.com');
 })();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   document.getElementById('nextbtn').disabled = false;
   document.getElementById('nextbtn').onclick = function() {
      window.open('https://www.youtube.com');
   };
</script>
```

//---

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML Document</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function countWord() {
            var x = document.getElementById("code").value;
            if ((x.length) != 12) {
                document.getElementById("ok").disabled = true;
            } else if ((x.length) == 12) {
                document.getElementById("ok").disabled = false;
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        * {
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
            box-sizing:border-box;
        }
        body {
            background-color:#fff;
        }
        #code {
            width:98%;
            margin-left:1%;
        }
        #ok {
            width:50%;
            margin-left:25%;
            margin-top:10px;
        }
        #nextbtn {
            width:50%;
            margin-left:25%;
            margin-top:10px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" name="code_form" id="code_form">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="code" id="code" onkeyup="countWord();">
        <input type="submit" name="ok" id="ok" class="btn btn-primary" disabled>
    </form>
    <button type="button" disabled class="btn btn-primary" id="nextbtn">Next</button>

    <?php
    //$conn = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");
    if (isset($_POST["ok"])) {
        $code = $_POST["code"];
        //$sql = "SELECT * FROM code WHERE code='$code'";
        //$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        //if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1) {
        if (1 == 1) {
            echo "<script>
        document.getElementById('nextbtn').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('nextbtn').onclick = function() {
            window.open('https://www.youtube.com');
        };
    </script>";
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('Error');</script>";
        }
    }
    ?>
</body>
```